# Is it correct to say that an integer is congruent with a p-adic number $\text{mod }p^k$?

Tags: notation, modular-arithmetic, p-adic-number-theory

Is there a standard way to describe a class of $p$-adic numbers that share the same final digits? E.g., if $x$ is a $p$-adic number and the last four digits of its $p$-adic representation are $\ldots abcd$, can we say that $x \equiv {c*p + d} \pmod {p^2}$?

Furthermore, what if $x$ is a $p$-adic fraction, and its last four digits are $\ldots ab.cd$? Surely we can't say $x \equiv \frac{c*p+d}{p^2} \pmod {p^{-2}}$?

Comment: Yes to the first. No to the second, you would write $x\equiv\frac{x}{p}+\frac{d}{p^2}\pmod{1}$.

Comment: Can I ask what your definition of the $p$ adic integers is? Is it from completion in the $p$-adic metric? Inverse limit of $\mathbb Z/p^n$? The answer is the same (as @runway44 indicates), but the best explanation for you will depend on your foundation.

Comment: I suppose I'd say that the p-adic numbers can be expressed as sums with the form $\sum_{i=j} a_i * p^i$ with $0<a_i<p$; the p-adic integers are the limits of those sums that can be expressed with j >=0, and the p-adic fractions are the ones for which j<0. I think this is equivalent to completion in the $p$-adic metric?

Comment: Beside the mathematical point, and maybe a native speaker will correct me, but I think in mathematical English one says "congruent *to*" (not *with*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The analogy with ordinary integers and rational numbers works well.

To your first question: yes, you can totally say that. Just like with integers, $x \equiv y \pmod{m}$ means nothing more nor less than $m$ divides $x-y$, and “divides” means that $x-y=mk$ for some integer $k$.

In your example, $p^2$ divides the difference between the given number and $cp+d$, because that difference is a $p$-adic integer without a free term and a multiple of $p$ term. All the terms have $p^2$ and beyond.

To your second question, consider what you’d say with ordinary rational numbers. If $q=17.25$ we don’t say that $q$ is congruent to $0.25$ modulo $\frac{1}{100}$. We can say that $q$ is congruent to $0.25$ modulo $1$, which means “up to adding some integer”. The same is true in the field of $p$-adic numbers.

The rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$ and the field $\mathbb{Q}_p$ of $p$-adic numbers are *fields*, so there’s no point in talking about congruence in the same way we do with rings such as the integers $\mathbb{Z}$ or the $p$-adic integers $\mathbb{Z}_p$. What we can say is that two elements differ by an integer.